# Criticize my math at finding radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n^2}z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n^2}z^{n}$
Let R be the radius of convergence. Then we have $\frac{1}{R} = \lim \sup |a^{n^2}|^{1/n} = \lim \sup |a|^{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [ \sup \{|a^{n}|,|a^{n+1}|,|a^{n+2}|,...\}] $

Then: $
\frac{1}{R}= \left\{\begin{matrix} \infty,  |a|>1 
\\ 1, |a| = 1
\\ |a|,  |a|<1
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Then 
$ R = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0, |a|>1
\\ 1, |a|=1
\\ \frac{1}{|a|}, |a|<1
\end{matrix}\right.$

I can feel there is something wrong with my answer. Can someone please check?
Thanks.

Comment: the $|a| < 1$ case is wrong, the rest are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|a| < 1$ then $|a|^n$ converges to $0$. Thus $\limsup\limits_n |a|^n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |a|^n = 0$.